# Como usar ou adicionar páginas aspx em um projeto Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, webforms, mvc

Dá para usar ou adicionar ao meu projeto que está em `Asp.net MVC` uma página que está pronta em `webforms` (aspx e cs) ?
Se sim como faço para adicionar a página ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá sim, o projeto MVC aceitar e roda as páginas aspx tranquilamente, basta clicar com o botão oposto e adicionar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é só eu clicar com o direito em cima do projeto e dar um add existing items ?